# Asus n56vz keyboard letter a not working properly

Tags: windows, keyboard

I have windows 7 installed on my laptop and the letter a is not working properly since 2 days ago. I already tried to uninstall the programs I installed since I noticed this problem, restarted windows 7. The problem is still there.

I'm thinking this is either a virus or the the problem is really the key. How can I be sure there isn't any issue with the key?

They key has several behaviours. Sometimes it simple doesn't work, sometimes I need to press several times in order to make it work (1 to 10 key presses).

Comment: Try cleaning under the key.

Comment: Try connecting the keyboard to another machine. See if the same behaviour is there. If it is, the keyboard is faulty, try cleaning under the key. If it isn't, the Windows machine may be infected.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting Ubuntu from a live CD and see if the problem persists. You can also plug an external keyboard to your laptop and test it in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a similar issue I occasionally have with my laptop: some of the number keys get 'stuck' and either don't input the number when depressed, or you have to hit the key a few times.

If your laptop has a USB port try plugging in a standard/full-size USB keyboard and trying the A key on that keyboard with several built-in programs like Notepad, WordPad, etc.

If the USB keyboard's A key works then that's at least a temp fix until you can disassemble the laptop for a permanent fix.